# Как работает лямбда-выражение

Tags: c#, делегаты, лямбда-выражения

есть такая вот программа

```
class Charging
{
    public Func<int, bool> BuildBattery(int capacity)
    {
        int rest = capacity;
        return delta =>
        {
            rest -= delta;
            if (rest < 0)
                return false;
            Console.Write(rest);
            return true;
        };
    }
}
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var charge = new Charging();
        var battery = charge.BuildBattery(7);
        for (var attempt = 1; battery(attempt); attempt++)
            Console.Write("+");
    }
}
```

- Интересует как работает лямбда-выражение в делегате `BuildBattery`. Поставил точку останова на
  `return delta =>`, и при запуске программы она сработала, только потом зашла в `Main`. Интересно почему так.
- Также интересует, почему каждый раз, когда происходит обращение к `return delta` значение `delta` увеличивается на 1. За счёт чего это происходит?
- Ну, и хотелось бы узнать как правильно называть эту конструкцию `return delta => { }`. Анонимный метод?

Comment: `BuildBattery` возвращает делегат. Делегат вызывается из Main. Потому туда и возвращает

Comment: в цикле `for (var attempt = 1; battery(attempt); attempt++)` вы сами вызываете делегат, передавая туда свой счетчик как параметр. Увеличиваете счетчик - вход на функции (delta) увеличивается

Comment: `delta => { }` [лямбда выражение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: Так увеличивается вход функции `BuildBattery`, но почему вместе с ним увеличивается и `delta`?

Comment: `BuildBattery` вызывается один раз с параметром 7, больше она нигде не вызывается, соответсвенно вход ее не увеличивается

Comment: Аа. Понял. Долго же до меня доходило, что при каждой итерации цикла вызывается не BuildBattery, а как раз лямбда-выражение. Спасибо большое!